# 404 ошибка, при выставление прямого пути к файлу в шаблоне django

Tags: python, django

Я хочу запустить готовую html страницу в django, но ни один файл (.css, .js и .jgp) не загружается и все файлы выдают 404.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
```

При том, что файлы расположены так:

```
-index.html
-img/
       -icon/
             -favicon-32x32.png
```

Несмотря на это я получаю ошибку 404. Относительно всех файлов включая .css, .js, итд..
Как сделать рабочим мой шаблон?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение самостоятельно, здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163630/django-referring-to-static-files-in-templates

Пути которые были указаны для файлов, использует сам браузер. Но для django нужно указывать полный путь, не из текущего каталога, а "абсолютный путь".

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).